# Reduce array and why if comparison does not work with or

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I created a program that reads a VPN output and it return the crypto maps with no encryption, but I have concern in the following things:

(1) Is is possible to reduce this array:

```
h.write(all_vpns[n-5]+all_vpns[n-4]+all_vpns[n-3]+all_vpns[n-2]+all_vpns[n-1]+all_vpns[n]+all_vpns[n+1]+"\n\n")
```

to something like

```
all_vpns[n-5]:all_vpns[n+1] or all_vpns[n-5]-all_vpns[n+1]
```

(2) There is a function that I used to remove all the lines from the file, which works well when there is only one rule in the if statement but when I add 2 it doesn't work:

```
with open(in_filename) as infile, open("clean_vpn.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        if line!='\n':
            outfile.write(line)
```

If in the if I add another argument it doesn't work

```
   if line!='\n' or line!='      \n':
```

Does someone know why the or is not working but as I mentioned before if I only have either argument it works fine for that statement but not both with the or?

Comment: use `line.strip()` to get read of white space at the edges so you don't need to cases for the end of line.

Comment: Avoid `if line!='\n' or line!='      \n':`. Use `line.strip() ; if line:` .

Answer (score 0):

(1) You could write less this way:

```
h.write(''.join(all_vpns[n-5:n+2])+'\n\n')
```

(2) The `if` in `if line!='\n' or line!=' \n'` will *always* evaluate to `True`. Because of the `or`. Lets check it for some values of `line`

- If `line` is `\n`, the first condition fails, but second one succeeds.
- If `line` is `' \n'`, the first condition succeeds.
- If `line` is anything else, both condition succeed.

So it is like no condition at all if you place `or`. I think you should use `and` instead of `or`.